# Inputing a value and instead of keeping that information in a array, it changes another var

Tags: c

I made a program and then it didn't worked. As in the other post someone advised me to trying to debug my programs, I learned it and debugged this one. Probably it has some basic errors of writting but that's because I've changed a lot of thing recently to understand what's happening. In third time when I input a value on screen on that loop, it changes my var "i" to that value instead of keeping that number in my array "grade".

First I tried to make it all in one loop, the first one, but as always it didn't help much, and then i wrote the code by this manner as you'll see

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int j=0,sum=0,i=0;
    int grade[]={0};
    for(;j<100;j++){
        printf("Type a grade:\t");
            scanf("%d",&grade[j]);
       if(grade[j]<10||grade[j]>20){
        break;
       }
    }
for(;i<j;i++){
    sum=sum+grade[i];
}
float average=sum/j;

  printf("The average is: %.2f\n",average);
  system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The exercicise says that you need to read "x" grades from a student and it needs to be between 10 and 20, if the number is out of this range it stops the loop.After I just need to calculate the average os these grades.I don't really know if my var average is being calculated correctly, cause I didn't could reach over there because of my problem. If you input 11, 12 and 13 it should give to a sum of 36, but gaves me 26, i don't know how.

Comment: regarding: `int grade[]={0};`  this is nonsense because the declaration of `grade[]` has not allocated any memory to be initializing to '0'

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces  2) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3)insert an appropriate space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Comment: regarding; `float average=sum/j;` this is performing integer math, so any remainder will be truncated.  Therefore, this will not perform the desired results.  Suggest: `float average = (float)sum/j;`

Comment: OT: regarding: `system("pause");`  not every OS has the command `pause` so this code is not portable  Suggest: int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;} getchar();``

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d",&grade[j])`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. 2) this results in undefined behavior as the array: `grade[]` has  no room for any thing.  Suggest changing the declaration of `grade[]  to `int grade[ 100 ] = {0};`

Comment: the posted code contains a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis  I.E. 100.  This makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement or a `enum` statement to give that number a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: thanks by the tips. I'm new in this world of programming, then sry for mistakes as identing the code. I'll try to put this in my future programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erik, you should define your array in a coherent way. To allow the necessary number of elements, try defining a numeric constant. You could use it for both define the number of iterations of your cycle and the size of your grade array. You can also avoid a new cycle to calculate the sum of the array, you can do this operation while reading the grades, using only one for loop. Try this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_GRADES 100

int main()
{
    int j,sum=0,i;
    float average;
    int grade[MAX_GRADES];

    for(j = 0 ; j < MAX_GRADES; j++)
    {
        printf("Type a grade:\t");
            scanf("%d",&i);

       if ( (i<10) || (i>20) )
        break;

      grade[j] = i;
      sum += i;
    }

  if (j > 0)
    average = (float)sum/j;
  else
    average = 0;

  printf("The average is: %d, %d, %.2f\n",sum, j, average);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome @Erik! I've added my explanation, I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks man, it helps me a lot. I need to learn how to think in another ways of thinking because in my mind i should keep the grades, sum them and after take the average, when i could skip some os these steps. Thanks again

Comment: I'm actually sleepy and didn't see the text before the code xD, sry.

Comment: I'm glad it helps. Have a nice day!

Comment: `sum/j` is an integer division, which is probably not wanted.